# What am I missing in this highly oscillatory integral?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, integration, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

I want to numerically integrate this equation (in python):

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm d}k f(k) J_v(r k)J_v(s k) $,

where f(k) is a non-smooth function, and $J_v$ are the Bessel function of the fist kind. In practice I have to integrate

$\int_{a}^{b}{\rm d}k f(k) J_v(r k)J_v(s k) $,

with usual values for $a \sim 10^{-8}$ and $b \sim 10^{16}$, where $f(k) \rightarrow 0$ for $b \ge 10^{16}$. I wrote a code based on [Levin's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042794001189) that partially solves my problem, with this method I can integrate up to 50 without much computational power. A exponential change of variables $k = 10^u$, helps me to integrate up to $\sim 10^2$.

Now, I can compute the integral for larger upper limits with more computational power but the error of the integral dramatically increase when I reach $b \sim 10^3$, pretty far for what I want to do.

I have tested this method in the case where $f(k) = k^{-p}$ and using the analytical solution of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9307213.pdf) and using Mathematica with the following instruction:

> NIntegrate[f[k]BesselJ[v,r k]BesselJ[v, s k], {k, a, b}, 
>    Method -> {"OscillatorySelection", Method -> "LevinRule", 
>      "FourierFiniteRangeMethod" -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}}]����

Somehow Mathematica deals with the integral nicely, much better than my code.

So, my question is: what am I missing? What does Mathetica do that I don't?

Any help or ideas are really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be one for mathematica.se?  It might also depend on the manner in which $f(k)$ is non-smooth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/